# How do you set the font in effect strip

Tags: text-object, effects

I can add a Text strip with the following code:

```
    effName = "eff" + tCStr[-3:]
    effName = sequences.new_effect(
        name=tField,
        type="TEXT",
        channel=tChan,
        frame_start=fStart,
        frame_end=fEnd)
```

I can also specify the location, size, color, and text content in my Python script, but I have not been able to change the font.

Can some kind soul please give me a clue how to do this?

I know the following don't work:

```
fnt = bpy.data.fonts.load(tFont)

bpy.ops.font.open(tFont)

bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all[tField].font = tFont
```

Note: tFont has the full path to the font.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured this one out.

```
tFont = 'fonts/' + row3[7] + '.ttf' # read font from .csv data file
fnt = bpy.data.fonts.load(tFont) # load font
bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all[tField].font = fnt # change font
bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all[tField].text = 'Text' # use font
```